# Fixed cup bottom bracket removal

Tags: bottom-bracket, peugeot, french

I have a square tapered bottom bracket which I am trying to remove but the fixed cup is proving difficult to loosen. The bike is a Peugeout Princeton from the early 90s. I have heard older French bikes are not reverse threaded, would this likely be the case for this bike?
[image]

Comment: Fixed cups can be very tough to loosen regardless. What tooling are you using to remove it?

Comment: I am using a flat 36mm spanner at the moment. The shops near me don't have the special tool I may have to look online

Answer (score 1):

A large vice can be used to clamp the cup and the frame should provide enough leverage, especially since you've almost completely disassembled the bike. Use some penetrating oil from the inside of the BB. Give it some time to seep into the threads. A hair-dryer could be helpful but a hot air gun might damage the paint.

French BBs are usually right/right and on assembly, thread-locker may have been applied to the fixed cup. If the right cup is 35mm, the BB is French. The British standard is either 1.370" or 1.375", according to Sheldon Brown. https://www.sheldonbrown.com/gloss_bo-z.html#bottom

The article also gives suggestion for removal of the fixed cup.

Comment: Thanks, can't see any markings on it to see whether it is french or bs. The threads are 1" 375 which is the same as 35mm so I'm none the wiser as to which way it goes.